# Should I delete variables before the end of code?

Tags: python, variables, caching, garbage-collection, del

Is it worth **deleting variables** from my **Python** code and using **gc.collect()** before the code ends? Won't the data be **automatically deleted** when the code finishes?

Simple example:

```
import gc

a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b

del a, b, c
gc.collect()
# end of code
```

Comment: Without using special functions like e. g. for shared nemory between multiple processes, memory is automatically freed when the program exits.

Comment: This is not only pointless in most cases, but can slow down your program's exit if you're freeing enough memory. Probably not noticeably so, but it could make a difference if you're running in a cloud environment where you're billed for time used, if the program is invoked frequently. Also it will use a minuscule amount of extra battery to do this if you're running on portable device. The way the operating system will do it (getting rid of the entire memory space your process is using) is quick and efficient.

Comment: No, it's pointless unless you are specifically messing with memory management. Python collects objects automatically when their reference count reaches 0, so they might get garbage collected even way earlier than when the code finishes, and it is guaranteed to free everything allocated when it does actually finish.

Comment: @kindall So is there any scenario where it would make sense to use del and gc.collect()?

Comment: If you're using more memory than you want to be using, and the memory you're using is not naturally being deallocated, then you can use those tools to manage memory better. For example, if you are processing large objects in a loop, then at the end of the loop, the loop variable will contain a reference to the last object processed. If there are no other references to that object, that variable might be the only thing keeping that memory from being freed. In that case you could `del` the variable (or just set it to `None`). But in a real program even that's probably not needed.